# Array not passing with ajax.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

This is the java script code for ajax call. In this case `code` variable get a c program code and pass it to the `compiler.php` page.

```
function insert(){
        var code = document.getElementById("file_cont").value;
        var arr = new Array(code,"c");
        alert(arr[0]);
    var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){          
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //window.location.assign("login.php");
                alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","server_controlers/compiler.php?q="+JSON.stringify(arr),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Ajax call work well but the case is in php file. I'm decode the jason array to `$arr` variable. But if i `echo` like this `echo $arr[0]` it is empty. But if i not include the `code` to the array in the java script like this `var arr = new Array("aaaa","c");` its works fine. Can some tell me what is the wrong when i send the array with `code` variable. This is the php file.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST["q"])){

    $arr = $_REQUEST["q"];
    $arr2 = json_decode($arr);

    echo $arr2[0];  
    /*$file = fopen("../temp_files/c/mmm.c","w");
    fwrite($file,"$arr[0]");
    fclose($file);
    shell_exec('gcc -ommm ../temp_files/c/mmm.c');
    system('mmm', $retval);*/
}else{

}

?>
```

Comment: What is `document.getElementById("file_cont")`? What is `document.getElementById("file_cont").value`?

Comment: @Quentin that is the text area which is a c code

Comment: What, specific, value does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server_controlers/compiler.php?q="+JSON.stringify(arr)
```

Your data is not being made URL safe. You say that it contains `c` code, this means it might include (for instance) the `&` character which would break the query string format and cause the JSON to be invalid when extracted from it.

You need to run the data through `encodeURIComponent` before putting it into your URL.

```
server_controlers/compiler.php?q=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(arr))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem in ur request type POST/GET. U shuffled 2 request types in 1. Also how i can see u try to send get request? but in parameters u use type POST.

[All information what u need about GET request u can find here.](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Also u can try change ur php code too. If u need to use POST

```
 <?php
     if($_POST){
     print($_POST);
     }
?>
```

After u can do all u need with data array.

Comment: The data is being sent in the query string, it won't show up in `$_POST`, it will show up in `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: xmlhttp.open("POST","server_controlers/compiler.php?q="+JSON.stringify(arr),true); So what mean that POST in his request then?

Comment: It means that it is a POST request with no POST data but with a query string that will appear in `$_GET`. Weird. Silly. Probably not what what intended. But not an immediate problem.

Comment: So then he send $_POST and $_GET request to server? I didn't see reason in that. Or maby i really stupid and didnt understand something.

Comment: There is no such thing as `$_POST` request or a `$_GET` request. There are POST requests and GET requests. Any request (except an OPTION request) can include a query string in the URL and that will be parsed to populate `$_GET` (and `$_REQUEST`). A POST request can include a message body which will be parsed to populate `$_POST` and `$_REQUEST`. Cookies will also be parsed and used to populate `$_REQUEST`.